# When are singleton objects constructed?

Tags: scala

In

```
object O {
  // construction code and member initialization
}
```

construct, when is this code going to be run?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code will be called when `O` is accessed the first time (some method or some property). For example the following program

```
object O {
  println("Hello from O")
  def doSome() {}
}

object App extends Application {
  println("Before O")
  O.doSome()
  println("After O")
}
```

will yield

```
Before O
Hello From O
After O
```

It's not enough to simply define `O`. Also it won't work to to call `Class.forName("O")` since the compiled object's name is `O$`, so calling `Class.forName("O$")` will do.

Comment: Regarding `Class.forName("O")`, that only won't work because the class name for `object O` is actually `"O$"`. If you call `java.lang.Class.forName("O$")`, it will indeed execute the initialisation block.

Comment: I see now that my answer is totally redundant.  Conclusion: I am a better answer writer than answer reader.

Answer (score 4):

In the interests of building self-reliance:

```
scala> object O { println("hi") }
defined module O

scala> O
hi
res0: O.type = O$@51d92803

scala> O
res1: O.type = O$@51d92803
```